# how to redirect network traffic in windows 8 to burp suite?

Tags: windows, networking, adhoc, netsh, burp

I have googled for this days and days. I have tried a lot of things but unfortunately did not succeed with any of them.

I have burp suite on my laptop running and listening to port 8080 on 127.0.0.1 as localhost, in order to intercept request from my iPhone I created Adhoc network which has ip addresses like this 192.168.137.xx.

My iPhone did connect to the Internet via the Adhoc network but I could not intercept any HTTP request in burp suite, I don't know what to do with this, I am totally frustrated.

In my iPhone network settings I defined proxy server which has the IP of my laptop running the burp suite which is 10.0.0.3 and the port 8080 but nothing is intercepted by burp what do I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly, we must make sure that we share the wifi on the windows computer correctly.**

```
 > netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="<SSID>" key="<PASSWORD>"
 > netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

[You can take a look at all the steps.](https://www.howtogeek.com/214080/how-to-turn-your-windows-pc-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/)

After sharing wifi, we need to connect with the phone and check that we have IP address.

**if there is no problem we can go to burp suite settings.**

[image: screen shot of settings]

**In the Burp suite proxy options we have to select the proxy listeners setting all interfaces option.**